# Clicking sound in left front when brakes are hot and I apply light brakes under 30 mph

Tags: brakes, pontiac, grand-am

I have a 2004 Grand Am and my mechanic is stumped. When my brakes are hot and when I apply them lightly under 30 mph there is a rotational clicking sound. But, get this, the sound isn't there when the brakes aren't hot and it isn't there at high speed or when braking hard. Only when lightly braking, slow speeds, and hot. Any ideas?

I had the caliper and brakes replaced a couple months ago. I went in a couple weeks ago with this problem and they replaced the brakes again on warranty. It went away for 2 weeks and now the sound is back. What could it be? It isn't there when the brakes aren't hot. And it isn't there when braking hard

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: When was the last brake job done on the front?

Answer (score 1):

A bolt may be coming loose or is not torqued (tightened) properly.  Metal things expand when heated, so at the cold temperature all parts may be in place.  As the assembly heats and expands, small gaps allow parts to jiggle.